# Sum of DropDownLists values inside a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hope someone can help me out with this problem. I have a GridView with x number of rows and in each row there are 4 columns consisting of 3 DropDownLists and a Label to hold the sum of the selected values of the 3 DropDownLists. My question is how do I accomplish this? I've tried the SelectedIndexChanged route for the DropDownLists but I'm not getting the results that I want. Instead of them being added, the values are being overwritten by the next selection. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I have so far:

```
    protected void ddlSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStuRoster.Rows)
        {
            double scores = 0;

            DropDownList ddlFocus = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlFocus");
            DropDownList ddlEvidence = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlEvidence");
            DropDownList ddlConventions = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlConventions");
            //DropDownList ddlScores = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlScores");
            Label lblScores = (Label)row.FindControl("lblScores");

            if (ddlFocus.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlFocus.SelectedValue != "-1")
            {
                scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlFocus.SelectedValue);
            }
            else if (ddlFocus.SelectedValue == "-1")
            {
                scores = -1;
            }

            if (ddlEvidence.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlEvidence.SelectedValue != "-1")
            {
                scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlEvidence.SelectedValue);
            }
            else if (ddlEvidence.SelectedValue == "-1")
            {
                scores = -1;
            }

            if (ddlConventions.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlConventions.SelectedValue != "-1")
            {
                scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlConventions.SelectedValue);
            }
            else if (ddlConventions.SelectedValue == "-1")
            {
                scores = -1;
            }

            lblScores.Text = scores == -1 ? "" : Convert.ToString(scores);
      }
    }
```

**Update**

After moving the `scores` and the `lblScores` label inside, everything intitially worked as expected except that on the first selection of any DropDownList, with the exception of the one in the same row, all the other Labels values in the GridView are set to 0. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scores` variable is reset to 0 on each request (each change of the drop down). Then, you're only setting `scores` to the value of the currently changing drop down. What you can do is get the value of each drop down on every request if the drop down has a selection. Assuming your drop downs each have their first item set as "Select a value" or something, you can check if the `SelectedIndex` is greater than 0 and if so it means there's a selection.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStuRoster.Rows)
{
    double scores = 0;

    DropDownList ddlFocus = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlFocus");
    DropDownList ddlEvidence = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlEvidence");
    DropDownList ddlConventions = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlConventions");
    Label lblScores = (Label)row.FindControl("lblScores");

    if (ddlFocus.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlFocus.SelectedValue);
    }

    if (ddlEvidence.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlEvidence.SelectedValue);
    }

    if (ddlConventions.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlConventions.SelectedValue);
    }

    lblScores.Text = scores == 0 ? "" : Convert.ToString(scores);
}
```

Comment: Dave, now I've ran into another problem. It looks like the score variable is persistent throughout the whole grid. The total from the first row is being added to the total in the second row.

Comment: You need to move the `scores` variable inside the loop, and set `lblTeacher` inside the loop as well. I've edited my answer to show this. Where is `lblTeacher` declared?

Comment: Dave, `lblTeacher` is a label that's outside the GridView that I'm using for testing purposes. In actuality, the sum of the scores are supposed to set to a label that's in the 4th column. I'll update my  OP to reflect that...After moving the `scores` variable inside the loop, I get back a value of zero no matter what I select.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your update. If you're setting `lblScores.Text` inside the loop it should work as expected. If not, set a breakpoint and check the value of scores as you step through the code.

Comment: I've added an **update** section to my OP stating what's going on after the code update.

Comment: I updated my answer. You were checking if `scores == -1`, where it should be checking if `scores == 0`. `scores` will never be -1.

Comment: Dave, after updating the code, the other Labels are still being set to an initial value. I've tested this by doing this - `ddlScores.SelectedValue = scores == 0 ? "-1" : Convert.ToString(scores);`. I even went as far removing the condittion and just value to `Convert.ToString(scores)` and still get the same result.

Comment: What is "an initial value"?

Comment: My bad for the confusion. I meant to say that it's still doing what I've mentioned in the update where the other Labels values are set to 0

Comment: Use the debugger to see what `scores` is on each iteration. For some reason `scores == 0` is not evaluating to what you want. I can't tell from here what it is.

Comment: From what I can see, while it's iterating thru each row, it's setting `lblScores` to 0 being that it hits the `double scores = 0;` at the beginning of the loop and skipping the skipping conditions.

Comment: The line `lblScores.Text = scores == 0 ? "" : Convert.ToString(scores);` should be setting it to the empty string if `scores` is still 0. `scores == 0` should result in `true`; if it's not then it must be comparing differently than expected. I can't really help you any more than this.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Dave, I was able to get the result that I wanted. Here's the final code that I have:

```
protected void ddlSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStuRoster.Rows)
    {
        double scores = 0;

        DropDownList ddlFocus = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlFocus");
        DropDownList ddlEvidence = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlEvidence");
        DropDownList ddlConventions = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlConventions");
        DropDownList ddlScores = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlScores");
        Label lblScores = (Label)row.FindControl("lblScores");

        if (ddlFocus.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlFocus.SelectedValue != "-1")
        {
            scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlFocus.SelectedValue);
        }

        if (ddlEvidence.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlEvidence.SelectedValue != "-1")
        {
            scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlEvidence.SelectedValue);
        }

        if (ddlConventions.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlConventions.SelectedValue != "-1")
        {
            scores += Convert.ToDouble(ddlConventions.SelectedValue);
        }

        ddlScores.SelectedValue = scores == 0 ? "" : Convert.ToString(scores);
    }
}
```

Thanks again, Dave!